# Rails: undefined method `abc_users_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to update some attributes of a devise user record remotely by using an method (`abc`) in the users controller.

**Routes**

```
    devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: "users/confirmations", omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

    resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :abc] do
        get "/abc" => "users#abc"
    end
```

**Users Controller**

```
def abc
    user = user.find(params[:id])
    params[:abc].each do |key, value|
        user.key = value
    end
    user.save!
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path) }
        format.js # render users/abc.js.erb
    end
end
```

**View**

```
= link_to(abc_users_path(current_user, abc: true), remote: true) do
    ABC
```

**The throwed error:**

> NoMethodError in Controller#method
> undefined method `abc_users_path' for #<#:0xc2ee630>

I appreaciate each answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `user_abc_path`, you can run`rails routes` in the console routes to verify.

Comment: If you are not using rails 5.0+ then the command would be `rake routes`